# How to remove the unwanted black region from binary image?

Tags: image-processing

I have binarized an image and calculate its black and white pixels. After pixel calculation, calculate the ratio of black pixels i.e. R= (no:of black pixels/ no: of white pixel+no: of black pixels)*100. I have to used this result to declare an eye is open or closed if R>20% then eye is in open state else closed. But when I calculate this ratio it is not coming what i want. I think there might be some error in calculation of black and white pixel, due to unwanted black region in image or might be problem in thresholding an image. I am using Otsu's method for thresholding [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g720A.png). 
While finding on this topic I also try `openInput=bwareaopen(bw, 80) but this is not work well to remove unwanted black area. Kindly help me out in removing the unwanted area.

```
close all
clear all
I=imread('op.jpg'); 
I=rgb2gray(I);
thres_level=graythresh(I); % find the threshold level of image
bw=im2bw(I,thres_level); % converts an image into binary
figure, imshow(bw);
totnumpix=numel(bw); % calculate total no of pixels in image
nwhite_open=sum(bw(:)); % calculate the black pixels in image;
nblack_open=totnumpix-nwhite_open; %calculate white pixels in image;
R=(nblack_open/(nblack_open+nwhite_open))*100
```

Comment: Your problem is not how to remove the unwanted black region but to find the eye. Why do you think this is the correct approach?
Try google `opencv eye detection` to get some other ideas

Comment: dear joseph First of all I am working in MATLAB, secondly i have successfully detected the eye from face region. Now third part is to topen track open and close eye, but when i am doing this using black/white ration approach ratio is not coming according to requirement, thats why i think it is correctly identify the black and white pixels

Answer (score 0):

The area opening erase areas having a surface smaller than the parameter you enter. In your case, it will not likely help.

I think that the black/white ratio is not the solution. I would either:

- Detect the iris (multiple effective papers/posts on the subject, mainly using hough transform), and if the detection fails, then the eye is closed.
- If you have the original color image, then use a skin detection (simple color thresholding in the HSV color space). Because the ratio of skin you will determine when the eye is closed.